# обьект должен преследовать другой обьект

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

подскажите как можно это реализовать: обьект должен преследовать игрока.Заранее спасибо .

Comment: `Vector3.movetowards(текущий объект, позиция куда идти, шаг);`

Comment: а позиция куда идти как ее выбрать

Comment: Либо по имени go, либо явно указать перетаскиванием самого transform

Answer (score 4):

Ответы по всем вопросам есть в официальной документации unity (ваш кэп)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

Скрипт должен висеть на объекте,который двигается за целью.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
// Цель к которой будем двигаться
public Transform target;

// Скорость персонажа в секунду
public float speed;

void Update()
{
    // Размер шага равен скорость * время кадра.
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Переместите нашу позицию на шаг ближе к цели.
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
}
```