# Использовал функцию Vecroe3.MoveTowards.но почему то объект не идет к цели

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

написал код подскажите почему объект не идет к цели.
первый класс при входе в большую зону (поле зрения врага )враг должен должен преследовать цель если при преследовании цель выходит из этой зоны то враг начинает хаотично двигать в течении 10 секунд .если в это время враг заметил то цикл начинается заново всм враг начинает преследовать цель а если враг не увидел цель то он просто остается на своем месте.

```
public class Trigger_for_enemy : MonoBehaviour {
// Цель к которой будем двигаться
public Transform target;
public Triggerforenemy hello;
public Enemykill kill;
// Скорость персонажа в секунду
public float speed;
float sec = 10f;
public float speed1 = 1.0f;
public float obstacleRange = 0.05f;
public float dist = 100f;



void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (kill.EnemyIsDead == false)
    {
        if (hello.stadia == 1)
        {
            transform.LookAt(target, Vector3.down);
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);//создаем луч первый параметр -откуда будет испускаться ,луч 2- куда.
            RaycastHit hit;//сталкнулся ли обьект 

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 50))
            {

                if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
                {
                    Debug.Log("попал");
                    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
                }
                else if (hit.collider.tag == "Untagged")
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else if (hello.stadia == 2 | hello.stadia == 3)
        {
            if (hello.stadia == 2)
            {

                sec -= Time.deltaTime;
                transform.Translate(0, 0, speed1 * Time.deltaTime);
                Ray ray1 = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);//создаем луч первый параметр -откуда будет испускаться ,луч 2- куда
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.SphereCast(ray1, 0.75f, out hit))
                {
                    if (hit.distance < obstacleRange)
                    {
                        float angle = Random.Range(-110, 110);
                        transform.Rotate(0, angle, 0);
                    }


                    if (sec <= 0)
                    {
                        hello.stadia = 3;
                        sec = 5;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

}

вот второй класс:при входе в маленькую зону и нажатии клавиши враг умирает

```
public class Enemykill : MonoBehaviour {
bool isTriggered = false;
bool isButtonUp = false;
public bool EnemyIsDead = false;


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)//чтобы враг умер
{

    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        isTriggered = true;
    }
}



void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isTriggered)
    {
        // Debug.Log("ghbdtn");
        StartCoroutine(TimerTick());
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    { isButtonUp = true; }
    if (isTriggered == true & EnemyIsDead == true & Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
    {
        Debug.Log("hvhgukguy");
    }
}
private IEnumerator TimerTick()
{
    if (isButtonUp)
        yield break;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    //таймер прошел. чудити что хотите
    EnemyIsDead = true;
    Debug.Log("враг умер");
    //обьект должен упасть

}
```

}

вот третий он отвечает за вход в большую зону

```
public class Triggerforenemy : MonoBehaviour {
public float sec = 5;
public int stadia = 0;//1-когда перс  вошел в триггер и враг его перследует   2-когда перс вышел из тригеера и враг должен ходить и искать его 3-когда враг возвращается на свое место или что то другое



private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        stadia = 1;
       // Debug.Log("в триггере");

    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{

    if (other.tag == "Player")
    { stadia = 2; }

}}
```

вот краткий код где именно ошибка`if (true)
            {
                transform.LookAt(target, Vector3.down);
                Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);//создаем луч первый параметр -откуда будет испускаться ,луч 2- куда.
                RaycastHit hit;//сталкнулся ли обьект

```
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 50))
            {

                if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
                {

                    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
                }

            }
        }`
```

обьект поворачивается к цели но почему то не идет к ней

Comment: Здорово, миллиард непонятных проверок, рейкасты, какие-то стадии и тэги. Вы как себе представляете дебаг всего этого?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(10);` в `FixedUpdate` для чего?

Comment: я все проверил все идет правильно но почему то обьект не передвигается

Comment: @RiotBr3aker выше

Comment: Здорово, что вы все проверили, мне или любому другому человеку как этот код у себя запустить? Приведите **минимальный воспроизводимый пример** https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  щас я вам весь код скину

Comment: Мне не нужен весь ваш код, повторяю, приложите **минимальный воспроизводимый пример**, а иначе вопрос следует закрыть.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker правил

Comment: Вы, видимо, не видите, что я вам написал уже 2 раза.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker сейчас все сделаю

Comment: @RiotBr3aker все

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  так пойдет

Comment: пишет что попал но не идет в сторону цели  @RiotBr3aker

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88257/discussion-between-riotbr3aker-and-danchikon10).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927277/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82/927296#927296

Comment: @TEA у него 1в1 такой код.

Comment: @TEA ДАК Я ТАК ЖЕ ВРОДЕ СДЕЛАЛ

Comment: НО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ,

Comment: @danchikon10 если не работает,то не так(к чему капс?)